# Why am I getting a TaskCanceledException with VS 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, exception, f#, compiler-warnings

I installed the brand new Visual Studio 2017 and now I am seeing this warning in the `Error List` window:

`Analyzer 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.FSharp.Editor.SimplifyNameDiagnosticAnalyzer' threw an exception of type 'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException' with message 'A task was canceled.'.`

The line of the error is 1.

The warning is generated even after I start a new project with only the following code:

```
let add x y = x + y

printfn "%i" (add 39999 500000)

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    printfn "%A" argv
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

The warning does not appear immediately after I run the code above. It takes a while to show on the screen.

Any ideas on what is happening?

Comment: Yes, you're using VS2017 RTW, that's what's happening. I assume this is related to [Issue #2550](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/2550), [Issue #2100](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/2100), and possibly  [Issue #2548](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/2548). It appears to be fixed in the Latest master VSIX, but you're back to where you were yesterday. Any reason you don't want to use VS2015 until these kinks get ironed out?

Comment: Indeed #2550 looks like the same problem. I want to use VS 2017 because it is more user-friendly.

Comment: It works fine on my VS 2017.  My version: Microsoft Visual F# 4.1, VisualStudio/15.0.0/RTW+26228.4

Comment: Which version are you running?

Comment: @DaveS It happens with both F# 4.0 and F# 4.1. From s952163's comment above one sees that the issue has already been identified and will be dealt with shortly (hopefully).

Comment: @Soldalma - My build is newer than the one's quoted above. I'm running Visual Studio 2017 PRO official release as I described above. No errors and no warnings.